# SageMaker: Collect Results from Uncompleted / In-Progress Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have a large SageMaker job that has more tasks than I need completed. I'd like to collect all worker-completed annotations prematurely. Is there a way to do this?

I have "Number of workers per dataset object" set to 5. None of my tasks have reached that threshold, but all have been labeled by at least 1 worker. I'd like to collect that data, but I see no way to do so. In my experience, "stopping" the job or checking the intermediate output manifest do not result in any output data for an incomplete job. Help?

If this isn't possible, it's a severe limitation that will impact the way we create labeling jobs in the future.